# Android Studio emulator: "Could not access the Package Manager." and "AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'emulator-5556' not found"

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem with the emulator in Android Studio. I took the version with the ARM Systems Image.

When I started the app, this error came into the run-app console on the bottom:

```
Target device: Nexus_S_API_23_2_ARM [emulator-5556]
Installing APK:C:\Users\Martin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication4\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.example.martin.myapplication.app
Installing com.example.martin.myapplication.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.martin.myapplication.app"
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.martin.myapplication.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.martin.myapplication.app"
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'emulator-5556' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Genymotion emulator. Its fast as compared to the emulator provided by Android studio. Search about Genymotion. Its really awesome